# Validation failed for one or more entities

Tags: entity-framework-4

I have following code in my asp.net MVC3 application:

```
string msg = "Beginning report run for: ";
            msg += " Obligor Registry ID: " + obligorID;
            msg += " Requesting Organization Registry ID:" + requestingOrgID;
            msg += " Requesting Agent Registry ID: " + requestingAgentID;

            TransactionLog lg = new TransactionLog();
            lg.TransactionTypeId = 2;
            lg.Message = msg;    


             context.TransactionLogs.Add(lg);
             long referenceNumber = context.SaveChanges();
            return referenceNumber;
```

and I am getting following error:

```
Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.
```

Comment: Nice and what did you find in details of the exception?

Comment: I have pasted the details above: Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.

Comment: The exception messages says that you should check its `EntityValidationErrors` property for more information ...

Comment: See answers to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7795300/validation-failed-for-one-or-more-entities-see-entityvalidationerrors-propert

Answer (score 16, accepted):

While you are in debug mode within the `catch {...}` block open up the "QuickWatch" window (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd>) and paste in there:

`((System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException)ex).EntityValidationErrors`

This will allow you to drill down into the `ValidationErrors` tree. It's the easiest way I've found to get instant insight into these errors.

Answer (score 2):

```
catch (DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
{
    foreach (var validationErrors in dbEx.EntityValidationErrors)
    {
        foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
        {
            Trace.TraceInformation("Property: {0} Error: {1}", validationError.PropertyName, validationError.ErrorMessage);
        }
    }
}
```

You need the namespace: System.Data.Entity.Validation

Answer (score 1):

@GONeale helped me out in this regard. Moreover cause for this exception in my case is that I have certain not null db fields which I didnt included in the partial response update for certain transaction. context.Database.ExecuteSQLCommand would be my suggestion in this case.