# Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1

I am having this error when seeding my database with code first approach.

> Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.

To be honest I don't know how to check the content of the validation errors. Visual Studio shows me that it's an array with 8 objects, so 8 validation errors.

This was working with my previous model, but I made a few changes that I explain below:

- I had an enum called Status, I changed it to a class called Status
- I changed the class ApplicantsPositionHistory to have 2 foreign key to the same table

Excuse me for the long code, but I have to paste it all.  The exception is thrown in the last line of the following code.

```
namespace Data.Model
{  
    public class Position
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]   
        public int PositionID { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Position name is required.")]
        [StringLength(20, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "Name should not be longer than 20 characters.")]
        [Display(Name = "Position name")]              
        public string name { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Number of years is required")] 
        [Display(Name = "Number of years")]        
        public int yearsExperienceRequired { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<ApplicantPosition> applicantPosition { get; set; }
    }

    public class Applicant
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]      
        public int ApplicantID { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name is required")] 
        [StringLength(20, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage="Name should not be longer than 20 characters.")]
        [Display(Name = "First and LastName")]
        public string name { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Telephone number is required")] 
        [StringLength(10, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "Telephone should not be longer than 20 characters.")]
        [Display(Name = "Telephone Number")]
        public string telephone { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Skype username is required")] 
        [StringLength(10, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "Skype user should not be longer than 20 characters.")]
        [Display(Name = "Skype Username")]
        public string skypeuser { get; set; }

        public byte[] photo { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<ApplicantPosition> applicantPosition { get; set; }
    }

    public class ApplicantPosition
    {
        [Key]
        [Column("ApplicantID", Order = 0)]
        public int ApplicantID { get; set; }

        [Key]
        [Column("PositionID", Order = 1)]
        public int PositionID { get; set; }

        public virtual Position Position { get; set; }

        public virtual Applicant Applicant { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Applied date is required")] 
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        [Display(Name = "Date applied")]     
        public DateTime appliedDate { get; set; }

        [Column("StatusID", Order = 0)]
        public int StatusID { get; set; }

        public Status CurrentStatus { get; set; }

        //[NotMapped]
        //public int numberOfApplicantsApplied
        //{
        //    get
        //    {
        //        int query =
        //             (from ap in Position
        //              where ap.Status == (int)Status.Applied
        //              select ap
        //                  ).Count();
        //        return query;
        //    }
        //}
    }

    public class Address
    {
        [StringLength(20, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "Country should not be longer than 20 characters.")]
        public string Country { get; set; }

        [StringLength(20, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "City  should not be longer than 20 characters.")]
        public string City { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "Address  should not be longer than 50 characters.")]
        [Display(Name = "Address Line 1")]     
        public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Address Line 2")]
        public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }   
    }

    public class ApplicationPositionHistory
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int ApplicationPositionHistoryID { get; set; }

        public ApplicantPosition applicantPosition { get; set; }

        [Column("oldStatusID")]
        public int oldStatusID { get; set; }

        [Column("newStatusID")]
        public int newStatusID { get; set; }

        public Status oldStatus { get; set; }

        public Status newStatus { get; set; }

        [StringLength(500, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "Comments  should not be longer than 500 characters.")]
        [Display(Name = "Comments")]
        public string comments { get; set; }

        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        [Display(Name = "Date")]     
        public DateTime dateModified { get; set; }
    }

    public class Status
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int StatusID { get; set; }

        [StringLength(20, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "Status  should not be longer than 20 characters.")]
        [Display(Name = "Status")]
        public string status { get; set; }
    }
}
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.IO;

namespace Data.Model
{
    public class HRContextInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<HRContext>
    {
        protected override void Seed(HRContext context)
        {
            #region Status
            Status applied = new Status() { status = "Applied" };
            Status reviewedByHR = new Status() { status = "Reviewed By HR" };
            Status approvedByHR = new Status() { status = "Approved by HR" };
            Status rejectedByHR = new Status() { status = "Rejected by HR" };
            Status assignedToTechnicalDepartment = new Status() { status = "Assigned to Technical Department" };
            Status approvedByTechnicalDepartment = new Status() { status = "Approved by Technical Department" };
            Status rejectedByTechnicalDepartment = new Status() { status = "Rejected by Technical Department" };

            Status assignedToGeneralManager = new Status() { status = "Assigned to General Manager" };
            Status approvedByGeneralManager = new Status() { status = "Approved by General Manager" };
            Status rejectedByGeneralManager = new Status() { status = "Rejected by General Manager" };

            context.Status.Add(applied);
            context.Status.Add(reviewedByHR);
            context.Status.Add(approvedByHR);
            context.Status.Add(rejectedByHR);
            context.Status.Add(assignedToTechnicalDepartment);
            context.Status.Add(approvedByTechnicalDepartment);
            context.Status.Add(rejectedByTechnicalDepartment);
            context.Status.Add(assignedToGeneralManager);
            context.Status.Add(approvedByGeneralManager);
            context.Status.Add(rejectedByGeneralManager); 
            #endregion    

            #region Position
            Position netdeveloper = new Position() { name = ".net developer", yearsExperienceRequired = 5 };
            Position javadeveloper = new Position() { name = "java developer", yearsExperienceRequired = 5 };
            context.Positions.Add(netdeveloper);
            context.Positions.Add(javadeveloper); 
            #endregion

            #region Applicants
            Applicant luis = new Applicant()
            {
                name = "Luis",
                skypeuser = "le.valencia",
                telephone = "0491732825",
                photo = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Users\LUIS.SIMBIOS\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\SlnHR\HRRazorForms\Content\pictures\1.jpg")
            };

            Applicant john = new Applicant()
            {
                name = "John",
                skypeuser = "jo.valencia",
                telephone = "3435343543",
                photo = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Users\LUIS.SIMBIOS\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\SlnHR\HRRazorForms\Content\pictures\2.jpg")
            };

            context.Applicants.Add(luis);
            context.Applicants.Add(john); 
            #endregion

            #region ApplicantsPositions
            ApplicantPosition appicantposition = new ApplicantPosition()
            {
                Applicant = luis,
                Position = netdeveloper,
                appliedDate = DateTime.Today,
                StatusID = 1
            };

            ApplicantPosition appicantposition2 = new ApplicantPosition()
            {
                Applicant = john,
                Position = javadeveloper,
                appliedDate = DateTime.Today,
                StatusID = 1
            };        

            context.ApplicantsPositions.Add(appicantposition);            
            context.ApplicantsPositions.Add(appicantposition2); 
            #endregion

            context.SaveChanges(); --->> Error here
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1352, accepted):

> To be honest I don't know how to check the content of the validation errors. Visual Studio shows me that it's an array with 8 objects, so 8 validation errors.

Actually you should see the errors if you drill into that array in Visual studio during debug. But you can also catch the exception and then write out the errors to some logging store or the console:

```
try
{
    // Your code...
    // Could also be before try if you know the exception occurs in SaveChanges

    context.SaveChanges();
}
catch (DbEntityValidationException e)
{
    foreach (var eve in e.EntityValidationErrors)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Entity of type \"{0}\" in state \"{1}\" has the following validation errors:",
            eve.Entry.Entity.GetType().Name, eve.Entry.State);
        foreach (var ve in eve.ValidationErrors)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("- Property: \"{0}\", Error: \"{1}\"",
                ve.PropertyName, ve.ErrorMessage);
        }
    }
    throw;
}
```

`EntityValidationErrors` is a collection which represents the entities which couldn't be validated successfully, and the inner collection `ValidationErrors` per entity is a list of errors on property level.

These validation messages are usually helpful enough to find the source of the problem.

**Edit**

A few slight improvements:

The *value* of the offending property can be included in the inner loop like so:

```
        foreach (var ve in eve.ValidationErrors)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("- Property: \"{0}\", Value: \"{1}\", Error: \"{2}\"",
                ve.PropertyName,
                eve.Entry.CurrentValues.GetValue<object>(ve.PropertyName),
                ve.ErrorMessage);
        }
```

While debugging `Debug.Write` might be preferable over `Console.WriteLine` as it works in all kind of applications, not only console applications (thanks to @Bart for his note in the comments below).

For web applications that are in production and that use **Elmah** for exception logging it turned out to be very useful for me to create a custom exception and overwrite `SaveChanges` in order to throw this new exception.

The custom exception type looks like this:

```
public class FormattedDbEntityValidationException : Exception
{
    public FormattedDbEntityValidationException(DbEntityValidationException innerException) :
        base(null, innerException)
    {
    }

    public override string Message
    {
        get
        {
            var innerException = InnerException as DbEntityValidationException;
            if (innerException != null)
            {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                sb.AppendLine();
                sb.AppendLine();
                foreach (var eve in innerException.EntityValidationErrors)
                {
                    sb.AppendLine(string.Format("- Entity of type \"{0}\" in state \"{1}\" has the following validation errors:",
                        eve.Entry.Entity.GetType().FullName, eve.Entry.State));
                    foreach (var ve in eve.ValidationErrors)
                    {
                        sb.AppendLine(string.Format("-- Property: \"{0}\", Value: \"{1}\", Error: \"{2}\"",
                            ve.PropertyName,
                            eve.Entry.CurrentValues.GetValue<object>(ve.PropertyName),
                            ve.ErrorMessage));
                    }
                }
                sb.AppendLine();

                return sb.ToString();
            }

            return base.Message;
        }
    }
}
```

And `SaveChanges` can be overwritten the following way:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    // ...

    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        try
        {
            return base.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbEntityValidationException e)
        {
            var newException = new FormattedDbEntityValidationException(e);
            throw newException;
        }
    }
}
```

A few remarks:

- The yellow error screen that Elmah shows in the web interface or in the sent emails (if you have configured that) now displays the validation details directly at the top of the message.
- Overwriting the `Message` property in the custom exception instead of overwriting `ToString()` has the benefit that the standard ASP.NET "Yellow screen of death (YSOD)" displays this message as well. In contrast to Elmah the YSOD apparently doesn't use `ToString()`, but both display the `Message` property.
- Wrapping the original `DbEntityValidationException` as inner exception ensures that the original stack trace will still be available and is displayed in Elmah and the YSOD.
- By setting a breakpoint on the line `throw newException;` you can simply inspect the `newException.Message` property as a text instead of drilling into the validation collections which is a bit awkward and doesn't seem to work easily for everyone (see comments below).

Comment: Drilling into the exception does nothing. It just says there is a DbEntityValidationResult but does not let you expand!!

Comment: @Shumii See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6593432/1080891) to expand the exception.

Comment: Just to extend an elegant solution. You may want to override the savechanges method in your own DbContext class, and then add try catch block, where the try block just try to save (base.SaveChanges()), and the catch block catches only DbEntityValidationException. This way, you don't need to add it in every place you save your changes.

Comment: Is it possible to get the value of the offending property?

Comment: This has saved my bacon on more than one occasion. I could only upvote once. Wished they'd let me upvote for every time I've copied and pasted this.

Comment: +2 for the code. Indeed a savior :) -1 for using `Console.WriteLine`, I estimate more people are writing web projects then console apps nowadays, and `Debug.Write` works in both...

Comment: This was new thing i now know, EntityValidationErrors property is not accessible if I catch general exception. Thanks.

Comment: @LeonardoHerrera: Your question is very old but only recently I found how to get the value of the offending property: `eve.Entry.CurrentValues.GetValue<object>(ve.PropertyName)` (see also the Edit section in my answer above).

Comment: This was really helpful, but instead of overloading the Entity Context I edited my database.Context.tt file to auto generate the savechanges overload.

Comment: They ought to fix this. The amount of time I've wasted looking this up again and again.

Comment: If the problem is seeding data, you can use this in your seed core to debug and watch validation errors: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16718510/debugging-package-manager-console-update-database-seed-method

Comment: Thanks! My error was: "User name my@email.com is already taken." When i tried to create a new entry (many to many relationship).

Comment: I found this code didn't work when the invalid property was a ComplexType. See my answer below for an updated version that handles this case.

Comment: thanks. this helped me to exactly pin point the issue. I had required attribute in one of the properties in the entity but i was not passing the values so this exception was being thrown. I was struggling to find out what was causing the issue.

Comment: @Slauma Thanks man, I really appreciate your work, Very good answer.Thanks a lot.

Comment: Since I was running into this problem in a unit test, it took a while to figure out that I needed to add a reference to System.Data assembly and using System.Data.Entity.Validation statement.

Comment: Kind of annoying that `DbEntityValidationException` doesn't include this data in its `ToString`

Answer (score 497):

You can do it from Visual Studio during debugging without writing any code, not even a catch block.

Just add a watch with the name:

```
((System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException)$exception).EntityValidationErrors
```

The watch expression `$exception` displays any exception thrown in the current context, even if it has not been caught and assigned to a variable.

Based on http://mattrandle.me/viewing-entityvalidationerrors-in-visual-studio/

Comment: +1 Way better solution, and does not require changes to code. Cool

Comment: +1 this is so very, very handy! You don't even need to have a try/catch block. Just stick this in the watch list when VS breaks and voila.. you've got the validation errors in front of you.

Comment: a couple of times a year I forget how to do this and find this answer

Comment: When I debug vb.net code, the watch window gives a value of "Character is not valid." Is there a difference between C# and VB watch expressions?

Comment: @zairja I haven't tested it in vb.net, but it appears that the variable is defined for vb.net as well in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164891.aspx, however the cast is probably not defined for vb.net, and instead you should probably do DirectCast ($exception,System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException)

Comment: I know that "thanks" are not welcome in comments but for the sake of preventing me hours of wasted time... thanks!

Comment: throws not in context error when i try to add this expression

Comment: Same issue as @ziaprog mentioned ^.  But silverfox1948's solution worked for me - context.GetValidationErrors()

Comment: This is the best and most elegant approach that works! It saves you time, no code change. Thanks!

Comment: Excellent, thank you. It helped me solve an problem whereby I had incorrectly defined a column in a table.

Comment: quick useful answer. cool!

Answer (score 118):

This could actually do it without having to write code:

In your catch block, add a break point at the following line of code:

```
catch (Exception exception)
{

}
```

Now if you hover on `exception` or add it to the `Watch` and then navigate into the exception details as shown below; you will see which particular column(s) is/ are causing the problem as this error usually occurs when a table-constraint is violated..

[image]

[Large image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BUbUV.png)

Comment: This approach is very simple and takes advantage of the IDE :)

Comment: This is a good solution because it is quick, simple, makes use of the IDE, and saved me a ton of time.

Comment: I like this way "How to be a coder and not to do code"

Comment: Thank you. This is simple but it is awesome to view the exception using IDE.

Comment: perfect solution

Comment: This solution is by far the easiest and the fastest way to see the actual error

Answer (score 59):

Here's how you can check the contents of the **EntityValidationErrors** in Visual Studio (without writing any extra code) i.e. during **Debugging** in the **IDE**.

#### The Problem?

You are right, the Visual Studio debugger's **View Details** Popup doesn't show the actual errors inside the `EntityValidationErrors` collection .

[image]

#### The Solution!

Just add the following expression in a **Quick Watch** window and click **Reevaluate**.

`((System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException)$exception).EntityValidationErrors`

In my case, see how I am able to expand into the `ValidationErrors` `List` inside the `EntityValidationErrors` collection

[image]

**References:** [mattrandle.me blog post](http://mattrandle.me/viewing-entityvalidationerrors-in-visual-studio/), [@yoel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24542325/325521)

Comment: why this hasn't been fixed? it should show the error not something else

Comment: The validation error shows the property error, ex. subject field is required, good answer, Thank you

Comment: Great! It saved my night! :)

Comment: this is smart way to visualize the exact error in watch...thank you!

Answer (score 41):

For a quick way to see the first error without even adding a watch you can paste this in the Immediate Window:

```
((System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException)$exception)
    .EntityValidationErrors.First()
    .ValidationErrors.First()
```

Comment: You can also use $exception.EntityValidationErrors.SelectMany(x => x.ValidationErrors).Select(x => x.ErrorMessage) to get all of them :) imho using the immediate window is the best answer

Answer (score 17):

For anyone who works in `VB.NET`

```
Try
Catch ex As DbEntityValidationException
    For Each a In ex.EntityValidationErrors
        For Each b In a.ValidationErrors
            Dim st1 As String = b.PropertyName
            Dim st2 As String = b.ErrorMessage
        Next
    Next
End Try
```

Answer (score 12):

While you are in debug mode within the `catch {...}` block open up the "QuickWatch" window (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd>) and paste in there:

`((System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException)ex).EntityValidationErrors`

*or:*

`((System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException)$exception).EntityValidationErrors`

If you are not in a try/catch or don't have access to the exception object.

This will allow you to drill down into the `ValidationErrors` tree. It's the easiest way I've found to get instant insight into these errors.

Answer (score 10):

If you are simply catching a generic exception, it may benefit you to cast this as a **DbEntityValidationException**.  This type of an exception has a Validation Errors property, and continuing to expand your way into them, you will find all the problems.

For example, if you put a break point in the catch, you can throw the following into a watch:

```
((System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException ) ex)
```

An example of an error is **if a field does not allow nulls, and you have a null string, you'll see it say that the field is required.**

Answer (score 9):

just Check Your Database Table Field Length . 
Your Input Text Is Greater than the length of column field data type length

Answer (score 9):

The answer from @Slauma is really great but I found that it didnt't work when a ComplexType property was invalid.

For example, say you have a property `Phone` of the complex type `PhoneNumber`. If the `AreaCode` property is invalid, the property name in `ve.PropertyNames` is "Phone.AreaCode". This causes the call to `eve.Entry.CurrentValues<object>(ve.PropertyName)` to fail.

To fix this, you can split the property name at each `.`, then recurse through the resulting array of property names. Finally, when you arrive at the bottom of the chain, you can simply return the value of the property.

Below is @Slauma's `FormattedDbEntityValidationException` class with support for ComplexTypes.

Enjoy!

```
[Serializable]
public class FormattedDbEntityValidationException : Exception
{
    public FormattedDbEntityValidationException(DbEntityValidationException innerException) :
        base(null, innerException)
    {
    }

    public override string Message
    {
        get
        {
            var innerException = InnerException as DbEntityValidationException;
            if (innerException == null) return base.Message;

            var sb = new StringBuilder();

            sb.AppendLine();
            sb.AppendLine();
            foreach (var eve in innerException.EntityValidationErrors)
            {
                sb.AppendLine(string.Format("- Entity of type \"{0}\" in state \"{1}\" has the following validation errors:",
                    eve.Entry.Entity.GetType().FullName, eve.Entry.State));
                foreach (var ve in eve.ValidationErrors)
                {
                    object value;
                    if (ve.PropertyName.Contains("."))
                    {
                        var propertyChain = ve.PropertyName.Split('.');
                        var complexProperty = eve.Entry.CurrentValues.GetValue<DbPropertyValues>(propertyChain.First());
                        value = GetComplexPropertyValue(complexProperty, propertyChain.Skip(1).ToArray());
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        value = eve.Entry.CurrentValues.GetValue<object>(ve.PropertyName);
                    }
                    sb.AppendLine(string.Format("-- Property: \"{0}\", Value: \"{1}\", Error: \"{2}\"",
                        ve.PropertyName,
                        value,
                        ve.ErrorMessage));
                }
            }
            sb.AppendLine();

            return sb.ToString();
        }
    }

    private static object GetComplexPropertyValue(DbPropertyValues propertyValues, string[] propertyChain)
    {
        var propertyName = propertyChain.First();
        return propertyChain.Count() == 1 
            ? propertyValues[propertyName] 
            : GetComplexPropertyValue((DbPropertyValues)propertyValues[propertyName], propertyChain.Skip(1).ToArray());
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't believe more people haven't upvoted this one, as it's a very real scenario and it's been driving me nuts the past two nights. You know that feeling you get when you realize your error handling is what's actually throwing the error? Ugh.

Answer (score 9):

In debug, you can enter this in your QuickWatch expression evaluator entry field:

```
context.GetValidationErrors()
```

Answer (score 9):

Was also struggling with this error and based on the topic here and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34435183) was able to figure out snippet to copy/paste without the need to figure out what has to be imported (excellent for C# beginners), code below:

```
try
{
  context.SaveChanges();
}
catch (System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException ex)
{
  foreach (var entityValidationErrors in ex.EntityValidationErrors)
  {
    foreach (var validationError in entityValidationErrors.ValidationErrors)
    {
      System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Property: " + validationError.PropertyName + " Error: " + validationError.ErrorMessage);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Note that `Entity.GetType().BaseType.Name` gives the type name you specified, not the one with all the hex digits in its name.

Answer (score 8):

I had to write this in the Immediate window :3

```
(((exception as System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException).EntityValidationErrors as System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationResult>)[0].ValidationErrors as System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbValidationError>)[0]
```

in order to get deep into the exact error !

EDIT:
Apparently there is a shorter and better version to get all errors, not just the first:

`$exception.EntityValidationErrors.SelectMany(x => x.ValidationErrors).Select(x => x.ErrorMessage)`

Answer (score 7):

Per @Slauma's answer and @Milton's suggestion I've extended our base class's custom save method with a try/catch that will handle (and hence log in our error logging!) these sorts of exceptions.

```
// Where `BaseDB` is your Entities object... (it could be `this` in a different design)
public void Save(bool? validateEntities = null)
{
    try
    {
        //Capture and set the validation state if we decide to
        bool validateOnSaveEnabledStartState = BaseDB.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled;
        if (validateEntities.HasValue)
            BaseDB.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = validateEntities.Value;

        BaseDB.SaveChanges();

        //Revert the validation state when done
        if (validateEntities.HasValue)
            BaseDB.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = validateOnSaveEnabledStartState;
    }
    catch (DbEntityValidationException e)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var eve in e.EntityValidationErrors)
        {
            sb.AppendLine(string.Format("Entity of type \"{0}\" in state \"{1}\" has the following validation errors:", 
                                            eve.Entry.Entity.GetType().Name,
                                            eve.Entry.State));
            foreach (var ve in eve.ValidationErrors)
            {
                sb.AppendLine(string.Format("- Property: \"{0}\", Error: \"{1}\"",
                                            ve.PropertyName,
                                            ve.ErrorMessage));
            }
        }
        throw new DbEntityValidationException(sb.ToString(), e);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use sb.AppendFormat() directly

Comment: You will need to add your own newline as well if you use AppendFormat.

Answer (score 6):

Using the answer of @Slauma i have made a code snippet (a surrounds with snippet) for better use.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CodeSnippets xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
  <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
    <Header>
      <SnippetTypes>
        <SnippetType>SurroundsWith</SnippetType>
      </SnippetTypes>
      <Title>ValidationErrorsTryCatch</Title>
      <Author>Phoenix</Author>
      <Description>
      </Description>
      <HelpUrl>
      </HelpUrl>
      <Shortcut>
      </Shortcut>
    </Header>
    <Snippet>
      <Code Language="csharp"><![CDATA[try
{
    $selected$ $end$
}
catch (System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException e)
{
    foreach (var eve in e.EntityValidationErrors)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Entity of type \"{0}\" in state \"{1}\" has the following validation errors:",
            eve.Entry.Entity.GetType().Name, eve.Entry.State);
        foreach (var ve in eve.ValidationErrors)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("- Property: \"{0}\", Error: \"{1}\"",
                ve.PropertyName, ve.ErrorMessage);
        }
    }
    throw;
}]]></Code>
    </Snippet>
  </CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>
```

Answer (score 5):

Catch the exception in a try catch and then quick watch or ctrl+d & ctrl+q and you can drill down to the EntityValidationErrors.

Answer (score 5):

Just throwing my two cents in...

Within my dbConfiguration.cs, I like to wrap my context.SaveChanges() method into a try/catch and produce an output text file that allows me to read the Error(s) clearly, and this code also timestamps them - handy if you run into more than one error at different times!

```
        try
        {
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbEntityValidationException e)
        {
            //Create empty list to capture Validation error(s)
            var outputLines = new List<string>();

            foreach (var eve in e.EntityValidationErrors)
            {
                outputLines.Add(
                    $"{DateTime.Now}: Entity of type \"{eve.Entry.Entity.GetType().Name}\" in state \"{eve.Entry.State}\" has the following validation errors:");
                outputLines.AddRange(eve.ValidationErrors.Select(ve =>
                    $"- Property: \"{ve.PropertyName}\", Error: \"{ve.ErrorMessage}\""));
            }
            //Write to external file
            File.AppendAllLines(@"c:\temp\dbErrors.txt", outputLines);
            throw;
        }
```

Answer (score 5):

What i found...when i got 'EntityValidationErrors' error is that....i have a field in my database 'db1' in table 'tbladdress' as 'address1' which has size of 100 (i.e address varchar(100) null) and i was passing value more than 100 characters..and this leading to error while saving data to database....

So you must Check the data you are passing to the field.

Comment: I appreciate this answer because it actually helped me resolve my error.  The table I was saving to in my db had all `not null` columns so once I added data to all elements prior to my `db.SaveChanges()` I received no error.

Answer (score 3):

This works for me.

```
var modelState = ModelState.Values;
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
{
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", model);
}
```

Put a breakpoint on if statement.
Then you can check modelState in debug windows. On every value you can see if there is an error and even the error message. That's it.
When you don't need it anymore, just delete or comment the line.

I hope this will help.

If asked, I can provide detailed screenshot in the debug window.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in other posts, simply catch the exception in DbEntityValidationException class.
Which will give you watever you required during error cases.

```
 try
 {
  ....
 }
 catch(DbEntityValidationException ex)
 {
  ....
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's another way to do it instead of using foreach loops for looking inside EntityValidationErrors. Of course you can format the message to your own liking :

```
try {
        // your code goes here...
    } 
catch (DbEntityValidationException ex) 
    {
        Console.Write($"Validation errors: {string.Join(Environment.NewLine, ex.EntityValidationErrors.SelectMany(vr => vr.ValidationErrors.Select(err => $"{err.PropertyName} - {err.ErrorMessage}")))}", ex);
        throw;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

In my case it was because of the length of the database field is less than the length of the input field.

**database table**

```
create table user(
  Username nvarchar(5) not  null
);
```

**My input**

```
User newUser = new User()
{
   Username = "123456"
};
```

the value for `Username` `length` is **5** which is `lessthan` 6

...this may help someone

Answer (score 2):

I faced this error before

when I tried to [update specific field in my model in entity framwork](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642371/how-to-update-only-one-field-using-entity-framework)

```
Letter letter = new Letter {ID = letterId, ExportNumber = letterExportNumber,EntityState = EntityState.Modified};
LetterService.ChangeExportNumberfor(letter);
//----------


public int ChangeExportNumber(Letter letter)
    {
        int result = 0;
        using (var db = ((LettersGeneratorEntities) GetContext()))
        {
            db.Letters.Attach(letter);
            db.Entry(letter).Property(x => x.ExportNumber).IsModified = true;
            result += db.SaveChanges();
        }
        return result;
    }
```

and according the above answers

I found the Validation message `The SignerName field is required.`

which pointing to field in my model

and when I checked my database schema I found

[image]

so off coure `ValidationException` has its right to raise

and according to this field I want it to be nullable, (I dont know how I messed it)

so I changed that field to allow Null, and by this my code will not give me this error again

> so This error maybe will happened if you invalidate Your Data integrity of your database

Comment: Whether or not an exception should be raised is not the point here. Next, you're cutting some corners here. When a field is required in the database schema you need more than that to have a `DbEntityValidationException` raised.

Answer (score 2):

Please check the fields value you are passing, are valid and according to database fields. For example number of characters passed in a particular field are less than the characters defined in database table field.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using **IIS** with **Windows Authentification** and **Entity Framework**, be careful to use `authorize`.

I tried to `POST` without authorize and it didn't work, and get this error on `db.SaveChangesAsync();`, while all other verbs `GET` and `DELETE` were working.

But when I added AuthorizeAttribute as annotation, it worked.

```
[Authorize]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post(...){
....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs mostly because of field size.
CHECK all the field sizes in a database table.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you have `Not Null` constraint in your table columns and you are not passes the value for that column while insert/Update operations.
That Causes this exception in entity framework.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same problem. I updated my .edmx from the database after that the exception has vanished.