# An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

i have the following EdiePOST action method:-

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "Note,DoctorID,VisitID,StatusID,timestamp")] Visit visit) //[Bind(Include="Note,DoctorID,VisitID,StatusID")]
        {
            if ((visit.EditableByAssingedDoctor(User.Identity.Name)) || (visit.EditableByCreatedBy(User.Identity.Name)))
            {

                try
                {
                    if (ModelState.IsValid)
                    {

                        int id = visit.VisitID;
                        var v = repository.GetVisit(id);
                        visit.CreatedBy = v.CreatedBy;
                        visit.Date = v.Date;
                        visit.PatientID = v.PatientID;
                        visit.VisitTypeID = v.VisitTypeID;


                        repository.UpdateVisit(visit);
                        repository.Save();
                        return RedirectToAction("Index");
                    }
                }
                catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
                {
//code goes here
```

where the `repository.UpdateVisit(visit);`is :-

```
 public void UpdateVisit(Visit v)
            {
                entities.Entry(v).State = EntityState.Modified;

            }
```

But when i run my application and i try to edit the visit object i got the following error :-

```
An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key.
```

on the `repository.UpdateVisit(visit);` method,, so what are going wrong?
BR

Comment: Couldn't tell you if this is causing your error, but it looks like you should be setting the variable v equal to the variable visit and then updating v instead of doing it the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

You are attaching two objects with the same key to the same context: `v` in `repository.GetVisit(id)` and `visit` in `repository.UpdateVisit(visit)`. This causes the exception.

Since you already load the entity from the database you can just update its properties and then save it. Instead of using...

```
repository.UpdateVisit(visit);
```

...use...

```
repository.UpdateAttachedVisit(v, visit);
```

...with:

```
public void UpdateAttachedVisit(Visit attachedVisit, Visit detachedVisit)
{
    entities.Entry(attachedVisit).CurrentValues.SetValues(detachedVisit);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, i tried ur code but it raised the following exception "System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException was unhandled by user code
  Message=Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.
  Source=EntityFramework"

Comment: @johnG: That's another error which has nothing to do with the first problem. You need to inspect the `EntityValidationErrors` as the message said, to find out the problem - either in debugger, or similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7798264/270591