# ASP.NET MVC - How to handle a string in a model that does not allow nulls?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, .net-4.5

So I'm a bit new to ASP.NET and MVC. I've got an ASP.NET MVC5 application, using Entity Framework 6.  I've generated my models from a SQL Server database, and am so far just using the vanilla index/create/details/edit constructs.

In my models, various fields are marked as "Allow Nulls" and others aren't.  While creating a new entry, any type that is, say, an int that is left as null is handled nicely by the `ModelState.IsValid` check and the `@Html.ValidationMessageFor` messages.

On one entry test, however, I received a `DbEntityValidationException`. I used the `try/catch` from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15820505/dbentityvalidationexception-how-can-i-easily-tell-what-caused-the-error) to find out that it was one of the string (`VARCHAR`) fields that was left blank.

I am assuming this is because the string class allows nulls, where as int does not (unless declared as `Nullable<type>` in the model) thus the controller/model doesn't flag it as invalid.

What would be the easiest way to handle this? Is there a way to decorate the string property in the model so it gets checked as well? Or do I need to go as far as attempting to save, catching the exception, and manually handling the validation messages?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to decorate your property with a [Required-attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.requiredattribute.aspx). Mvc wil show an error message when the user is posting a form while this property is empty.

```
public class TestClassModel
{
    [Required]
    public string RequiredString { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response and simple answer!

Comment: What if RequiredString will be null?

Comment: Then there will be an error in the ModelState and if the validation is turned on, the form on the page won't submit.