# DbEntityValidationException

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to 'delete' a record from a table in my view (not my database)... and I am receiving:

> An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException' occured in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code.

I have debugged, and the record that is going through the `DeleteConfirmed` Actionresult is correct, and all of the properties/fields are filled in, not one is left blank.

**Controller Action:**

```
[HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
{
    codePerson codePerson = db.codePerson.Find(id);
    codePerson.deleted = true;
    TryUpdateModel(codePerson);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

**MetaData Class:**

```
[MetadataType(typeof(MetaDatacodePerson))]
public partial class codePerson
{

}
public class MetaDatacodePerson
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [RegularExpression(@"^(\s+)?[\w.\\]+\s\w+\s\w+(\s+)?$", ErrorMessage = "Custom Error Message")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string IBM { get; set; }
    public string CategoryID { get; set; }
    public bool deleted { get; set; }
    public int LocationID { get; set; }
}
```

Why is this error occuring when all of the properties of `codePerson` are being populated?  All of these fields in my database do not accept nulls, and like I said above.. when debugging none of these fields are null, or emptyspace.

Comment: Do you have an `InnerException` on your returned Exception with more specific details on the exact validation that failed?

Comment: @Igor No i do not.

Comment: what's inside `TryUpdateModel`

Comment: I would start here.  First figure out which object is throwing the validation exception: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15820505/dbentityvalidationexception-how-can-i-easily-tell-what-caused-the-error