# Entity framework error when inserting model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Having problem with inserting a model to database with EF in a MVC application.

Im receiving following error when callning dbContext.SaveChanges() :

```
[DbEntityValidationException: Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.]
```

Any clue what this can be about?

Its strange because sometimes it works to make one insert but if i make another immediately after it crashes.

And sometimes it crashes on first insert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the accepted answer in this post: [Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7795300/validation-failed-for-one-or-more-entities-see-entityvalidationerrors-propert)

PS: Please remove error message details as it's of no use and it can expose private information.

Answer (score 0):

More than likely you have some property on the entity that is not nullable.  Most of the time when I get this error, that's the culprit.  Set a watch on the 'EntityValidationErrors' property, then in the debugger expand into this property and you will see the exact message that is being thrown.