# Uploading new row to database table Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

**LAST EDIT:**

There were various problems with my code, which are explained in the comments of two answers. In the end i've used the following code:

```
using (var context = new CijferDBEntities()) 
        { 
            context.Student.Add(newStudent);
            try
            {
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (DbEntityValidationException ex)
            {
                foreach (var entityValidationErrors in ex.EntityValidationErrors)
                {
                    foreach (var validationError in entityValidationErrors.ValidationErrors)
                    {
                        Console.Write("Property: " + validationError.PropertyName + " Error: " + validationError.ErrorMessage);
                    }
                }
            }

        }
```

**EDIT**: I've explained this badly, I'd like to know how I would insert a new student (which I created here) into the table `dbo.Student`.

---

I'd like to insert a new row into my table in the database using C#.

First have I defined a student here:

```
private void btnToevoegen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        EntityVoorbeeld vb = new EntityVoorbeeld();

        string Roepnaam = txtRoepnaam.Text;
        string Voegsel = txtVoegsel.Text;
        string Achternaam = txtAchternaam.Text;
        DateTime Geboortedatum = Convert.ToDateTime(txtGeboortedatum.Text);
        string Adres = txtAdres.Text;
        string Postcode = txtPostcode.Text;
        string Woonplaats = txtWoonplaats.Text;
        string Email = txtEmail.Text;
        string Telefoon = txtTelefoon.Text;
        string Mobiel = txtMobiel.Text;

        // Create new student
        Student newStudent = new Student();
        newStudent.Roepnaam = Roepnaam;
        newStudent.voegsel = Voegsel;
        newStudent.Achternaam = Achternaam;
        newStudent.Geboortedatum = Geboortedatum;
        newStudent.Adres = Adres;
        newStudent.Postcode = Postcode;
        newStudent.Woonplaats = Woonplaats;
        newStudent.Email = Email;
        newStudent.Telefoon = Telefoon;
        newStudent.Mobiel = Mobiel;

        // Add student to table
        vb.Studenten.add(newStudent);

        vb.SaveChanges();
}
```

which I want to be inserted into the table once the button is clicked.

I have used the following code to fetch the students from the database:

```
public ObservableCollection<Student> Studenten(string klas, string schooljaar)
{
        Lesgroep groep = ce.Lesgroep.SingleOrDefault(g => g.Naam == klas && g.Schooljaar == schooljaar);
        return new ObservableCollection<Student>(groep.Student.OrderBy(s => s.Achternaam).ThenBy(s => s.Roepnaam));
}
```

At this code:

```
vb.Studenten.add(newStudent);
```

i get the following error upon hovering over Studenten

```
'CijferDB.EntityVoorbeeld.Studenten(string, string)' is a 'method', which is not valid in the given context.
```

Turned out my DBSet was missing, i edited in the following:

```
public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
```

Comment: Could you clarify what error you are receiving? Assuming EntityVoorbeeld  is your dbContext this code should work.

Comment: Perhaps i have explained this wrong, the fetching of the database works fine now but i need help with inserting a new student into dbo.Student

Comment: Ok, do you get any exception when you insert the newStudent object?

Comment: I edited in the error at the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To summarize**:

1. It turns out that OP encounter `DbEntityValidationException` which
   is cause by one of the model field being null when inserting to
   database.
2. The DBSet `Student` that OP include in previous code is also causing
   the `newStudent` instance to not insert into database as he was not
   referring to his DbContext class, rather `EntityVoorbeeld`, a normal
   class which does not contain the DbSet `Student`.

Comment: The connection is working fine since i'm already fetching a ObservableCollection of Students, i have edited the post.

Comment: can you post your dbcontext class? i think the problem is that your are adding to the wrong dbset

Comment: @Wessah I'd read the comments on your post and it seems that you have encountered a DbEntityValidationException. Try to find out what causes the exception then only you can add student to database.

Comment: So i've debugged my code and found the following: It does not fill newStudent with the inserted data, but instead fills 'this' with all the data. [Here's a picture for reference](http://imgur.com/xnSxMoU)

Comment: Check whether all your strings variable have values because I only see string Mobiel with value of "d". The "this" is normal to have as it refers to itself when running code .

Comment: All strings variables have values, it just only displays the last one (which is mobiel). Why would newStudent be null though?

Comment: Ok i've read a bit more.. turns out it does insert the student locally, but still won't save the changes because of the DbEntityValidationException, which i think could be the ID being 0, it having no lesgroep, no resultaat or no studentcode[here's 3 screenshots](http://imgur.com/a/3YE9q)

Comment: I agree with @Jcl about looking into DbEntityValidation exception , you can show the exact error with the code provided by Romias in [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21606454/how-to-handle-system-data-entity-validation-dbentityvalidationexception)

Comment: I've seen that, but how do i make a seperate class? I can't just right click it and add a class..

Comment: no need to add class, just put the whole **public override int saveChanges(){.....}** into your CijferDBEntities class

Comment: This did it! I'll post the solution in the OP. It turned out that StudentCode was missing after all.. Thanks for your patience with me, i learned a lot these last days!

Comment: NP glad to help out :-)

Comment: btw can you post your own answer as accepted answer? this can help future readers not to get confuse by our long comments. Cheers~ :-)

Comment: I've edited in my own answer on top of the post, but since our exchange was pretty long with various problems i think it's better to keep it this way, no?

Comment: At least edit this answer with the valid one. As it is now, the "accepted answer" does not pose an answer to the original question. This might be ok now, but future readers will definitely be confused by this answer being accepted. Anyway, this question was TONS of questions indeed and it has been edited error after error. If it was me, I'd delete the question alltogether, because neither the question nor the answers make sense anymore

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps there is a violation of constraint , ensure that there is not violation of primary key

Answer (score 0):

`Studenten` is a method (which you are showing on your question). For adding a new entity you need to add it to your context's `DbSet`, not to a method that returns an `ObservableCollection`.

Your `DbContext` (by your code, the type `EntityVoorbeeld`) will have a `DbSet` property of type `Student` (with a name, that you are not providing). Use that name to add it:

```
vb.TheNameOfTheStudentDbSet.Add(newStudent);
vb.SaveChanges();
```

In English, that'd more likely be called `Students`, so your `EntityVoorbeeld` class would look something like:

```
public class EntityVoorbeeld : DbContext
{
   public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }     

   /* 
      ... the rest of your context's properties and methods ...
   */
}
```

But your names may vary.

Comment: It turns out i did not have the DBSet in there at all, i've inserted it now (see the bottom of OP) but vb.Students.add(newStudent); won't work yet because DBSet contains no definition for 'Add'.

Comment: @Wessah use title case (`Add`, not `add`). C# is case sensitive. [DbSet definitely has `Add`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.data.entity.dbset.add(v=vs.113).aspx)

Comment: Thanks, errors are gone but i get an expection telling me the connection doesn't work/the dbcontext is incorrect. Should i send a pastebin?

Comment: I'd say that should be a completely different question, but just in case it's a trivial error, paste the pastebin's link to code in the comments (not in the question, by any means)

Comment: Seems your `EntityVoorbeeId` is not the `DbContext`: did you just randomly add that? It looks like a repository. Your `DbContext` is `CijferDBEntities`, which you access from `EntityVoorbeeId` using the variable `ce`. You should add the `DbSet` property to `CijferDBEntities`

Comment: (I'm trying to understand it without understanding the variable names or comments, which is a bit hard, but it looks like that on your code)

Comment: So i've checked the definition of CijferDBEntities and it leads to CijferModel.Context.cs which looks like this http://pastebin.com/Y4mDcSXJ

Comment: So you already got your `Student` there. The minimum to add your student would be `using(var context = new CijferDBEntities()) { context.Student.Add(newStudent); context.SaveChanges(); }`

Comment: Of course, you should have methods in your repository to add a student if you are working using that pattern... but that's WAY outside the realm of this question (and probably for StackOverflow, unless you have *specific* questions, not just general "how-to" ones). Try to understand what your code is doing, do not randomly add this and that to see if it compiles and works :-)

Comment: Yeah i understand what you're saying and i try to not randomly add things but i would really like to get this working asap, i'm still a student so i'll eventually get the logic behind it, it just takes some time. So i figured i may have to create a method in `EntityVoorbeeld` to add the `NewStudent` into the table from there(as you can see the SaveChanges method is already there). I don't know how i'd create this method though, and if this is really the best way or fastest to do it.

Comment: The method could be as simple as my last comment

Comment: The method you wrote should be placed under where i defined NewStudent, right? Because when i tried that, i got the following on `context.SaveChanges();`: `An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll

Additional information: Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.`

Comment: That's again a completely different error. More likely some fields of the new student are wrong (invalid data or required data not entered, etc.) . The details of the exception should tell you what's wrong

Comment: So i don't know how i link comments but i've commented this to the other answer

Comment: @Wessah can we see the code of the `Student` class, and the code of the `CijferDBEntities` one? There you can probably see the validation constraints. ID being 0 *should* be no problem (it gets autogenerated), but there could be other constraints you are not filling properly

Comment: Doesn't look like there's any restriction or validation there. If it's a model-first (it looks like so), then there might be restrictions there. A careful study of the `DbEntityValidation` exception should give the cause(s) of the entity (the student)  being "rejected"

Comment: Check the comments with, @Shawn Yan, there should be more explanation there