# Update one table during edit operation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I am working on MVC application, there I am trying to update one table during edit operation. I am getting the following error.

> Validation failed for one or more entities. See
>   'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.

I searched no clue. Here is my code, any help please?

```
var hoteling = context.Hoteling.FirstOrDefault(h => h.HotelingId == modelData.HotelingId);

if (hoteling != null)
{
     hoteling.BookedBy = (string)Session["UserName"];
     hoteling.BookingType = Convert.ToInt32(modelData.BookingType);
     hoteling.Description = modelData.Description;
     hoteling.StartDate = modelData.StartDate;
     hoteling.EndDate = modelData.EndDate;
     hoteling.StartTime = modelData.StartTime;
     hoteling.EndTime = modelData.EndTime;
     hoteling.WorkSpaceRefId = modelData.WorkSpaceRefId;
     hoteling.ProjectId = 1;
     hoteling.RepeatDay = modelData.RepeatDay;
     hoteling.RepeatType = modelData.RepeatType;
     context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: That's obvious, there is a fail validation, wrap the code with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7795300/validation-failed-for-one-or-more-entities-see-entityvalidationerrors-propert) and see what's the error

Comment: @YuliamChandra Super useful tip, I really like the method. Honestly, I cannot understand why such a method is not used to display a more meaningful error to the deeloper

Comment: im sorry yliam i didnt understand what you are telling. How to do that please?

Comment: @user1557020, wrap the `context.SaveChanges();` code just like in the link, click [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7798264/968303)

Comment: i have done it before its is telling the cell is empty. what it mean

Comment: it means that the cell has to have a value, you might set the property as `[Required]`. Could you give list of properties that caused the error, from the link I gave, you can see it while debugging in `ve.PropertyName, ve.ErrorMessage`, also show your hoteling class..

Comment: It says "See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details." It doesn't look like you did this because these errors *always* tell you what's wrong.