# When I Fill the Create View and Submit It's throwing a DbEntityValidationException

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, exception, database-first

In this project i was trying a Entity Framework Code First Apporach

> ```
> Table 'Employee'
>
> Id           int               NOT NULL
> FirstName    nvarchar(50)      NOT NULL
> LastName     nvarchar(50)      NOT NULL
> MiddleName   nvarchar(50)      NULL
> Address      nvarchar(300)     NULL
> Salary       decimal(16,2)     NULL
> Email        nvarchar(50)      NULL
> ```

It's Perfectly done. Then I Added Entity Framework, Added A `EmployeeController`. Two Action Method `Index` & `Create` with their corresponding Views.
Are were so far perfect.

![enter image description here][1]  ![enter image description here][2]

### Then I Did the following for Employee Add:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Employee emp)
    {
        
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Employees.Add(emp);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(emp);

        
    }
```

When I Fill the `Create` View and Submit It's throwing a `DbEntityValidationException`

![enter image description here][3]

```
DbEntityValidationException was unhandled by user code

An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.
```

My Database Table is not updating too, now row created there.

Model definition

```
public partial class Employee
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string FirstName { get; set; }
  public string LastName { get; set; }
  public string MiddleName { get; set; }
  public string Address { get; set; }
  public Nullable<decimal> Salary { get; set; }
  public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Show us your `Employee` class definition.

Comment: what's in EntityValidationErrors ?

Comment: public partial class Employee
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string MiddleName { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> Salary { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }

Comment: Post your view as well.

Answer (score 0):

taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7795300/validation-failed-for-one-or-more-entities-see-entityvalidationerrors-propert)

add this code to your post method, it should help to understand errors you get in output window

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Employee emp)
{
     try
     {
         if (ModelState.IsValid)
         {
             db.Employees.Add(emp);
             db.SaveChanges();
             return RedirectToAction("Index");
         }
         return View(emp);     
     }
     catch (DbEntityValidationException e)
     {
         foreach (var eve in e.EntityValidationErrors)
         {
              System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Entity of type \"{0}\" in state \"{1}\" has the following validation errors:",
              eve.Entry.Entity.GetType().Name, eve.Entry.State);
              foreach (var ve in eve.ValidationErrors)
              {
                   System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("- Property: \"{0}\", Error: \"{1}\"",
                ve.PropertyName, ve.ErrorMessage);
              }
         }
         throw;
     }
}
```

Comment: sir, the bug remains same, my emp oject is getting values that i submit in the Create View but the update is not reflecting in the Database that's the issue. How would i fix ??

Comment: @KHArifAhmaad in debug mode did DbEntityValidationException  exception catched? What was written in output window?

Answer (score 0):

I hate that I cant comment yet, would have been easier to resolve.

Anyway, What I would do when adding a record is, bind the fields and create an instance of the model before saving. This also allows you to use, the much advised, ViewModels.

Change your action to this

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "FirstName,LastName,MiddleName,Address,Salary,Email")]Employee u)
{

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            Employee emp = new Employee
            {
                FirstName = u.FirstName,
                LastName = u.LastName,
                MiddleName = u.MiddleName,
                Address = u.Address,
                Salary = u.Salary,
                Email = u.Email
            };
            db.Employees.Add(emp);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(emp);
}
```

I didnt include a value for the `Id` Field as I assume this would be DB generated. If not, then `Id` would need to be included in `Bind` and you would need to add code to populate `Id` with in the initialization of `Employee emp`

In the event that `Id` is not DB generated, since I see your `Id` field is not nullable. To test whether this action code will work, you can do this:

```
Employee emp = new Employee
            {
                Id = 1,
                FirstName = u.FirstName,
                LastName = u.LastName,
                MiddleName = u.MiddleName,
                Address = u.Address,
                Salary = u.Salary,
                Email = u.Email
            };
```

1 last thing, to make your `Id` field DB generated, do this in your T-Sql code

```
Id           int         IDENTITY(1,1)      NOT NULL    PRIMARY KEY
```

Hope this sorts it out, or atleast is a first step.