# How to store additional information in ASP.Net Identity MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I'm using Identity on my application and as you all know there is no additional table or column to store information regarding users.
I need to create a table called UserProfile and save information like: First Name, Last Name, Gender and etc. of users during user registration.

I've already tested various ways which was posted on different websites but there was no luck. Many websites demonstrate on how to extend Users table but I need to add a second table.

Comment: Why do you need to add an additional table instead of just utilize the existing one?

Comment: Our company requires an additional table for user profile. I have mentioned that we can extend the existing one but they said no. :(

Comment: @CodeMaster Hi, I think I have the solution for your question. You can use my setup to fix your problem.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33201697/save-additional-profile-data-during-register-in-asp-net-identity-mvc/33212937#33212937

Comment: @KevinMaxwell, BIG THANK YOU. can you post your comment below?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned above, you can follow my setup and I hope it will help others too.

[Save additional profile data during "Register"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33201697/save-additional-profile-data-during-register-in-asp-net-identity-mvc/33212937)

Comment: If you answer solely exists as a link to another answer, you should flag the question as a duplicate.

Comment: You're right. It's done.