# EF6 Throws Exception for EntityValidationErrors When I Try to Update Entity

Tags: c#

I have a problem when I update entity in EF6. The code looks like this:

```
public PICCOSSourceCost GetCOSSourceCost(int sourceCostID)
{
    return ERPContext.PICCOSSourceCost.Where(sc => sc.ID == sourceCostID && !sc.Deleted).FirstOrDefault();
}
public PICCOSSourceCost UpdateCOSSourceCost(PICCOSSourceCost sourceCost, bool saveChanges = true)
{
    var sc = GetCOSSourceCost(sourceCost.ID);
    if (sc == null)
    {
        throw new PICObjectNotFoundException<PICCOSSourceCost>(sourceCost, new List<string>()
        {
            nameof(PICCOSSourceCost.PICCOSSourceID),
            nameof(PICCOSSourceCost.PICCOSPriceTypeID),
            nameof(PICCOSSourceCost.Price),
            nameof(PICCOSSourceCost.EffectiveDate)
        });
    }

    sc.PICCOSSourceID = sourceCost.PICCOSSourceID;
    sc.PICCOSPriceTypeID = sourceCost.PICCOSPriceTypeID;
    sc.Price = sourceCost.Price;
    sc.EffectiveDate = sourceCost.EffectiveDate;
    sc.Deleted = sourceCost.Deleted;
    sc.CreatedBy = sourceCost.CreatedBy;
    sc.CreatedDate = sourceCost.CreatedDate;
    sc.LastModifiedBy = sourceCost.LastModifiedBy;
    sc.LastModifiedDate = sourceCost.LastModifiedDate;

    if (saveChanges) ERPContext.SaveChanges();

    return sc;
}
```

As you can see that the "GetCOSSourceCost" method get entity from EF. And **the first parameter "sourceCost" in the "UpdateCOSSourceCost" method is passed in from FrontEnd, which is also got from EF6**.
When I debug the code, there is an "System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException" occurred. I don't know why. I think that it should be okay because I just get an entity object and just change its properties and save changes. Is it because there are two references to the same object?
***If I remove the property assignment code, the error will disappear.***

> Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.

Do you know why it throws this exception? Please help me. Thank you so much!

Comment: What does `Exception.EntityValidationErrors` contain?

Comment: It might help if you post your Entity and the Model binding

Comment: I use DB First to create EF models, and add entities into the model. I think "EntityValidationErrors" is just a message which means an error occurs when validating entities. the real exception type is "System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException"

Comment: Have you tried removing the property assignment lines and adding them back one by one?

Comment: @JefferyYou When the Exception is thrown, you should be able to inspect it (dependent on IDE), if not you can catch the exception `try { ... } catch (Exception ex) { Debugger.Break(); }` and then inspect the variable, which should contain a property called "EntityValidationErrors".

Comment: I appreciate your answer very much. I have found the root cause of the error by the link [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7795300/validation-failed-for-one-or-more-entities-see-entityvalidationerrors-propert). The root cause is that some required fields is NULL... Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Based on this

http://mattrandle.me/viewing-entityvalidationerrors-in-visual-studio/

You can use  is a special debugger variable- `$exception`

To view the EntityValidationErrors collection you can use below to show watch windows

```
((System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException)$exception).EntityValidationErrors
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help so much. I have solved my issue by the following link:
[Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7795300/validation-failed-for-one-or-more-entities-see-entityvalidationerrors-propert)
For the sake of this link, I debugged and find the root cause of the entity validation error. Some required fields are set to NULL value.
The code from the answer is very useful:

```
try
{
    // Your code...
    // Could also be before try if you know the exception occurs in SaveChanges
    context.SaveChanges();
}
catch (DbEntityValidationException e)
{
    foreach (var eve in e.EntityValidationErrors)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Entity of type \"{0}\" in state \"{1}\" has the following validation errors:", eve.Entry.Entity.GetType().Name, eve.Entry.State);
        foreach (var ve in eve.ValidationErrors)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("- Property: \"{0}\", Error: \"{1}\"", ve.PropertyName, ve.ErrorMessage);
        }
    }
    throw;
}
```