# Unable to add Data in sql database in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am trying to add a employee details in database table but I am Getting this error

```
 **Argument 1: cannot convert from 'MVCCRUDOPERTIONS.Models.DATABASE.emoloyee' to 'MVCCRUDOPERTIONS.Models.DATABASE.employee' MVCCRUDOPERTIONS C:\Users\user\source\repos\MVCCRUDOPERTIONS\MVCCRUDOPERTIONS\ViewModels\HOME\EmployeeViewModel.cs 26 Active**
```

since I am new in asp.net I am unable to sort this on my own.any help would be appreciated.

Comment: emoloyee? At least fix the typo.

Comment: now I am getting this error  'Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.'

Comment: @theCoder Refer to this link for your above error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7795300/validation-failed-for-one-or-more-entities-see-entityvalidationerrors-propert and also it would be great if you can show how you are adding your data to your database.

Answer (score 1):

**emoloyee** and **employee** are two different classes

Comment: now I am getting this error  'Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.'

Comment: @theCoder Did you see EntityValidationErrors property for more details? What did it say?