# Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have Three dropdowns multi-select list and I am using an array of integer type in my ViewModel to store the Valu of selected items from the list.I am getting the following exception

**Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.'**
when I removed these arrays from ViewModel then there is no exception.

```
//ViewModel
public class DependancyMatrixVM
    {

        public int DM_Id { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Cal_Tag_P_Id { get; set; }

        public int?[] MF_Tag_Id_FK { get; set; }
        public int?[] Cal_Tag_Id_FK { get; set; }

        public int?[] Real_Tag_Id_FK { get; set; }



    }
```

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7795300/validation-failed-for-one-or-more-entities-see-entityvalidationerrors-propert?rq=1 & check what is error inside `EntityValidationErrors`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7795300/validation-failed-for-one-or-more-entities-see-entityvalidationerrors-propert)