# DbEntityValidationException while saving List of objects ef code-first SQL Server CE database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, sql-server-ce

I have a SQL Server CE database configured with Entity Framework code-first with a model class `InfoLog` as follows:

```
public class InfoLog
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Item { get; set; }
}
```

And I save list of logs to this table using,

```
conn.InfoLog.AddRange(items.Select(x => new InfoLog { Item = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(x) }));
```

And after certain time I sync those logs with server and flush it from database using,

```
conObj.InfoLog.RemoveRange(itemsToFlush);
```

Now usually (For months for hundreds of users) it works perfectly fine, but all of sudden I start getting following error (for some random user),

> System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException: Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.
>
> at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()
>   at DataService.SaveInfoLog(List`1 items)

It clearly state to check `EntityValidationErrors`, but I am unable to replicate that, even with the same SQL Server CE database on which the issue is occurring.

Now with model specified above what kind of `EntityValidationError` could occur is really tough question for me.

And I am impatient to wait for next time it occurs, can anyone suggest how can I proceed to solve this.

**Update**:

- If we debug with same database, then records get saved.
- And on end user machine if we restart application then also records get saved.

Comment: are you not able to find out what error(s) has occurred from EntityValidationErrors property? you should be able to find it in debug mode - Quickwatch
if not, you can catch the error and try to log the errors.
this answer might help : https://stackoverflow.com/a/7798264/5407080

Comment: Unfortunately, even when we debug with same db, records gets saved successfully, Though if we start application on end user machine then it gets saved successfully, Now getting confused whether it is issue at application (ef) end or sql server ce end.